# What kind of encoding is this ? And what script should I use to decode this?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, formatting

I have an encode string which I have to convert to a form which has HTML tags and display it in a webview. The encoded data I have is of this format :-

*Having+a+pet+is+quite+like+parenting%2C+you+just+cannot+stand+the+chance+being+away+from+them.+Still%2C+very+often+it+occurs+that+you+cannot+have+your+pets+around+everywhere+so+you+need+to+shelter+them+elsewhere+for+a+while.+But+at+the+end+of+the+day%2C+one+must+admit+that+it+is+pretty+hard+to+trust+anyone+with+our+furry+babies.+Who+knows+them+better+than+us%2C+their+habits%2C+eating+orders%2C+temperaments+and+socialization+tendencies%3F%0D%0A%0D%0AIt+is+because+of+this+very+reason+that+we+at+%3Ca+href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsuplife.in%2Fnoida%22+target%3D%22_blank%22+rel%3D%22noopener%22%3EWhat%92s+Up+Noida+are+sharing%3C%2Fa%3E+with+you+the+list+of+5+pet+boarding+facilities+which+you+can+actually+trust.%0D%0A%3Ch4%3E%3Cstrong%3EThe+Dog+Resorts%2C+Noida+%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fh4%3E%0D%0AAt+the+Dog+Resort+Noida%2C+be+assured+that+your+pet+will+be+cared+for+by+thorough+professionals.+%A0They+resort+boasts+of+a+10%2C000+sq.+ft.+premises+area+where+about+5000+sq+.ft+is+wide+open+green+area+to+make+your+pet+stay+playful+and+cheering.+The+best+aspect+about+the+place+is+that+there+is+complete+medical+care+and+behavioral+apprehending+of+pets+as+they+have+a+dedicated+team+of+veterinary+doctors%2C+dog+trainers%2C+and+other+pet+care+expertise.%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Ca+href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsuplife.in%2Fnoida%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F06%2FDog-resort-noida.png%22%3E%3Cimg+class%3D%22aligncenter+wp-image-4902+size-full%22+src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsuplife.in%2Fnoida%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F06%2FDog-resort-noida.png%22+alt%3D%22Dog+resort+noida%22+width%3D%221052%22+height%3D%22326%22+%2F%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3EAddress%3A%A0+Sector+112%2C+Noida%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3E+Contact%3A+9911782646%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0D%0A%3Ch4%3E%3Cstrong%3EBest+Pet+Boarding+%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fh4%3E%0D%0AThey+are+indeed+one+of+the+highly+rated+and+positively+reviewed+pet+boarding+facilities+in+Noida.+Not+just+for+dogs+but+they+have+a+friendly+providence+of+pet+care+and+day+boarding+services+for+other+pets+like+fish%2C+bird%2C+guinea+pig%2C+hamster%2C+cat%2C+and+others+as+well.%A0+The+idea+of+creating+is+%91no-cage%92+free+space+for+beloved+pets+was+developed+by+Kaveri+Rana+Bhardwaj+and+Yashraj+Bhardwaj.+At+the+Best+Pet+Boarding%2C+the+emphasis+is+on+making+your+pet+socialize+and+have+a+free+will+of+wandering+in+wide+space.+They+believe+in+the+unique+concept+of+letting+in+a+trained+dog+which+said+to+be+their+%91alpha%92+among+other+pet+dogs%2C+this+maintains+the+decorum+all+the+time.%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Ca+href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsuplife.in%2Fnoida%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F06%2Fbest-pet-boarding.jpg%22%3E%3Cimg+class%3D%22aligncenter+wp-image-4903+size-full%22+src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsuplife.in%2Fnoida%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F06%2Fbest-pet-boarding.jpg%22+alt%3D%22best+pet+boarding+noida%22+width%3D%22960%22+height%3D%22489%22+%2F%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3EAddress%3A+B+14+1+Omicron+2%2C+Greater+Noida%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3E+Phone%3A+09711951179%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0D%0A%3Ch4%3E%3Cstrong%3EPet+Home+Affairs+Day+Boarding+%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fh4%3E%0D%0A%3Ca+style%3D%22font-size%3A+14px%3B+font-family%3A+%27Open+Sans%27%2C+Arial%2C+sans-serif%3B+color%3A+%2319232d%3B+text-decoration-line%3A+underline%3B%22+href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsuplife.in%2Fnoida%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F06%2Fpet-home-affairs-day-care.jpg%22%3E%3Cimg+class%3D%22alignright+wp-image-4906+size-full%22+style%3D%22font-size%3A+14px%3B%22+src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsuplife.in%2Fnoida%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F06%2Fpet-home-affairs-day-care.jpg%22+alt%3D%22pet+boarding+in+noida%22+width%3D%22350%22+height%3D%22263%22+%2F%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0A%0D%0APet+Home+Affairs+enjoys+a+sterling+reputation+in+pet+care+industry+and+is+one+of+the+remarkable+services+in+Noida.+At+the+boarding%2C+there+are+professionals+who+understand+the+needs+of+your+pet+and+also+your+preferences+about+the+specific+services+you+need+for+your+pet.+Pet+care+system+is+well+scheduled+for+meal+and+medicine+timings+and+under+the+care+of+pet+care+experts+here.%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3EAddress%3A%A0+Supertech+Capetown%2C+Sector+74%2C+Noida.%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3E+Phone%3A+09873204636%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0D%0A%3Ch4%3E%3Cstrong%3EClean+Cute+%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fh4%3E%0D%0AWith+their+10%2C000+sq.+ft+wide+space+of+Dog+day+care+and+pet+holiday+home%2C+Clean+Cute+is+known+to+serve+all+sizes%2C+kinds%2C+breeds%2C+and+age+of+pets.+They+are+biggest+and+best+boarding+facility+not+only+in+Noida+but+also+in+NCR.+Clean+Cute+is+managed+by+a+highly+skilled+dog+handling+team+offering+pet+grooming+services%2C+recreational+activities%2C+health+care%2C+therapies%2C+pet+parenting+counseling%2C+dog+behavior+management%2C+skin+care%2C+dog+rehabilitation+and+actually%2C+what+not.%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Ca+href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsuplife.in%2Fnoida%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F06%2FBoarding-Large-File.jpg%22%3E%3Cimg+class%3D%22aligncenter+wp-image-4907+size-large%22+src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsuplife.in%2Fnoida%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F06%2FBoarding-Large-File-1024x682.jpg%22+alt%3D%22dog+boarding+in+noida%22+width%3D%22702%22+height%3D%22468%22+%2F%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%26nbsp%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3EAddress%3A%A0+Sector+112%2C+Noida%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3E+Phone%3A+08076548163%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0D%0A%3Ch4%3E%3Cstrong%3EGoDogee+Pet+services+%3C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%2Fh4%3E%0D%0AGoDogee+is+one+of+the+India%92s+leading+pet+care+services+providing+pet+day+care%2C+pet+hotel%2C+pet+grooming%2C+pet+vaccination%2C+pet+treatment%2C+pet+mating+and+other+interesting+and+unique+sort+of+services.%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cimg+class%3D%22aligncenter+size-full+wp-image-4905%22+src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsuplife.in%2Fnoida%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F06%2Fgodogee.jpg%22+alt%3D%22%22+width%3D%221920%22+height%3D%22790%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3EAddress%3A+J-10%2C+Noida+Rd%2C+H+Block%2C+Sector+8%2C+Noida%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3E+Phone%3A+09910664343%3C%2Fstrong%3E*

What kind of format is this and how do I convert it into text with html tags ?

I'm currently using this method but I'm getting a nil return value :

```
func urlDecode(_ htmlString: String) -> String {

    var decodedURL = htmlString.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: " ")
    decodedURL = decodedURL.removingPercentEncoding!
    return decodedURL
}
```

Comment: That’s basic URL encoding ...

Comment: @shallowThought - rolled back your edit, understand why you did it but it unfortunately removed the clue to the problem in the process.

Comment: @CRD OK. Sorry. I thought I took care to leave certain `%0A`s. No worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are getting `nil`, which means that there is something in your string that is invalid. How could we find out what? Well it's certainly not spaces, so let's break your string into "words":

```
var decodedURL = htmlString.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: " ")
let chunks = decodedURL.components(separatedBy: " ")
```

and now try to decode each "word" and see which ones fail:

```
for chunk in chunks
{
   let decoded = chunk.removingPercentEncoding
   if decoded == nil
   {
      print("\(chunk)")
   }
}
```

this outputs:

```
rel%3D%22noopener%22%3EWhat%92s
%A0They
%2F%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3EAddress%3A%A0
well.%A0
%91no-cage%92
%91alpha%92
here.%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3EAddress%3A%A0
%2F%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%26nbsp%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3EAddress%3A%A0
India%92s
```

Now `removingPercentEncoding` decodes UTF-8, so checking each of those % sequences to see if they are valid UTF-8 shows that %91, %92 & %A0 are not. However they are valid Windows-1252 encodings - single curly quotes and the non-breaking space.

So you need to decode the string as Windows-1252 not UTF-8. Time for you to look in the documentation...

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I've been beating my head since the last 3 hours. The rest of the responses I got from the API were UTF-8 encoded, so I presumed this would be the sam too. I'll try decoding the string as Windows - 1252 now, cheers !

Comment: @AkshayYerneni: Reducing the input to a *minimal* example demonstrating the problem is actually *your* part, *before* posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

From apple,

> A new string with the percent-encoded sequences removed, or nil if the
>   receiver contains an invalid percent-encoding sequence.You must call
>   this method only on strings that you know to be percent-encoded.
>   Calling this method on strings that are not percent-encoded can lead
>   to misinterpreting a percent character as the beginning of a
>   percent-encoded sequence.

You get nil because `removingPercentEncoding` does not recognize some of your percent encoding. I pasted it onto [online parser](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) and find out that %A0 and %92 seem to be suspicious.